# How to stagger adding/removing multiple classes to a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a logo to fade out and a smaller version fade in on scroll. It's currently working great in terms of scaling on scroll ([see JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/voLk7fu3/4/)) but now I need it to fade on top of that and I don't know where I'm going wrong ([see JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/by92srh4/1/)), it's currently not smooth. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**JS:**

```
function scrollAnimation() {
  if ($(window).width() > 640){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 50) {
      $(".inner").addClass('scrolling');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".inner").removeClass('hide-logo').addClass('show-logo');
      }, 500);
    }
    else {
      $(".inner").addClass('hide-logo').removeClass('show-logo scrolling');
    };
  } else {
    $(".inner").removeClass('show-logo scrolling');
    $(".inner").addClass('hide-logo');
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
  scrollAnimation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS parameter `transition-delay` provides a means of staggering when a transition starts. That means that you can trigger the transition when you first scroll down and then have the secondary action occur after some time.

In cases where you cannot simply delay the start but need to listen for a transition to end before doing something then there is a `transitionend` event which you can bind a handler to.

```js
// store the logo state
var logoFullSize = true;

// add listener to trigger fade-in once fade-out has finished
$(".site-header").bind('transitionend', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('fade-out')
});


function scrollAnimation() {
  // removed this logic so demo works in stackoverflow
  // if ($(window).width() > 640) {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 50 && logoFullSize) { // change to small logo
      $(".logo").addClass('scrolling');
      $(".site-header").addClass('fade-out');
      logoFullSize = false;
    }

    if (scrollTop < 50 && !logoFullSize) { // change to full-size logo
      $(".logo").removeClass('scrolling');
      $(".site-header").addClass('fade-out');
      logoFullSize = true;
    }
  //}
}

$(window).on('scroll resize', scrollAnimation);
```

```css
.site-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-timing-function: easeInExpo;
}

img.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 5%;
  transition-property: height;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

img.scrolling {
  height: 50px;
}

.site-header.fade-out {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-header">
  <span class="inner">
  <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/c/c8/Twitter_Bird.svg" />
  </span>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pro case commodo docendi, denique periculis vix ad. Eam eu laboramus conceptam reprimique, quis tacimates pericula in eam, cum ei amet commune. Pri porro atomorum ut, at augue graece torquatos vim. Dolore gubergren mea ut,
    ex sit munere ancillae delicata.
  </p>
  <p>
    Antiopam oportere ea duo. Ut per vidit accusata neglegentur. Te quem utamur eam. Mea vidit illum tacimates ne.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cu summo viderer quaeque per. Utinam electram sed et. Ius no accusamus vulputate, vis dicant delectus deserunt ne. Appareat ponderum delicatissimi vis ut, ut alia mucius sea. Perpetua consulatu temporibus vix ad, error accommodare in sea.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ex est mollis dolores inciderint, eu vix quas assum blandit, vis ad enim nihil nusquam. Cu iusto veniam suavitate duo. Mundi oratio perpetua id ius, cu usu facilisis dissentiet. Saepe debitis detraxit id per, te debitis instructior pro. Id ignota epicuri
    rationibus vis, dicam noster ex ius, ad cum dico mazim persequeris.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duo minim audiam regione at, an qui qualisque prodesset. Ex doming habemus delicatissimi sit, cum ad pertinax molestiae, ea nam agam fabellas. Quaeque aliquid ceteros id vix, vis omnium suavitate explicari ex. Cum an quas meliore.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pro case commodo docendi, denique periculis vix ad. Eam eu laboramus conceptam reprimique, quis tacimates pericula in eam, cum ei amet commune. Pri porro atomorum ut, at augue graece torquatos vim. Dolore gubergren mea ut,
    ex sit munere ancillae delicata.
  </p>
  <p>
    Antiopam oportere ea duo. Ut per vidit accusata neglegentur. Te quem utamur eam. Mea vidit illum tacimates ne.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cu summo viderer quaeque per. Utinam electram sed et. Ius no accusamus vulputate, vis dicant delectus deserunt ne. Appareat ponderum delicatissimi vis ut, ut alia mucius sea. Perpetua consulatu temporibus vix ad, error accommodare in sea.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ex est mollis dolores inciderint, eu vix quas assum blandit, vis ad enim nihil nusquam. Cu iusto veniam suavitate duo. Mundi oratio perpetua id ius, cu usu facilisis dissentiet. Saepe debitis detraxit id per, te debitis instructior pro. Id ignota epicuri
    rationibus vis, dicam noster ex ius, ad cum dico mazim persequeris.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duo minim audiam regione at, an qui qualisque prodesset. Ex doming habemus delicatissimi sit, cum ad pertinax molestiae, ea nam agam fabellas. Quaeque aliquid ceteros id vix, vis omnium suavitate explicari ex. Cum an quas meliore.
  </p>
</div>
```